# SBT: how to prevent scala-library from being added to pom automatically?

Tags: java, scala, sbt, pom.xml

In a project that consists of Java-only sources with Scala tests and which is built with SBT 0.11.2, I have followed [the instructions to have the artifacts uploaded to Maven Central](https://github.com/sbt/sbt.github.com/blob/gen-master/src/jekyll/using_sonatype.md). This worked fine, except for the fact that scala-library is listed as a compile-time dependency in the pom, which I don't want, because it would cause the users of my library to pull scala as a transitive dependency. Is there a way to prevent this dependency from being added?

The exact build.sbt I use can be seen [on github](https://github.com/mmakowski/clisson-protocol/blob/15e8da6499d3e96d5808a85951a15e8a1a5a5dc7/build.sbt).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your build.sbt set `autoScalaLibrary := false` this removes the dependency to the scala-library.